# How to write or send messege to particular person in whatsApp through my app?

Tags: android, integration, whatsapp

Is there any way to send messege to particular person or contact in whatsapp through My app.
I didn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of sending message to a particular contact in whatsapp.

But there is one of doing it by using [Accessibility service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html), for that you need to take permission from user.

As an example, you can see this app [Stickons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voodoo.stickons&hl=en)